# Variance of present value of annuity

Tags: probability-theory, actuarial-science

Let $Y$ be a present value of whole life annuity that pays $1$ for year of each $x$-years old. We know that $\ddot{a}_x=10$ for $i'=1/24=e^\delta-1$ and $\ddot{a}_x=6$ for $i=e^{2\delta}-1$. I want to calculate the variance of $Y$. To be honest I don't know where to start.

I want to use the equation:

$$VarY=\frac{^2A_x-(A_x)^2}{d^2}.$$
Where: $$A_x=\sum_{j=0}^\infty v^{j+1} {}_j| q_{x};$$
$$^2 A_x=\sum_{j=0}^\infty (v^2)^{j+1} {}_j| q_{x}$$
Also we have: $\ddot{a}_x=\frac{1-A_x}{d}$ where $d=\frac{i}{1+i}$

The definition of $\ddot{a}_x=\sum_{j=0}^\infty v^j\  _{j}p_x$ and $v=\frac{1}{1+i}$.

All I can think of is to calculate $\delta$ and other constants as $v$ and $d$  for $i'$ and $i$ but I don't really know where it should go from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve for $A_x$ and ${}^2 A_x$ using the formula $\ddot{a}_x = \frac{1-A_x}{d}$ with the two given values for $\ddot{a}_x$.  Then you can solve for $\delta$ using the given $e^\delta - 1 = 1/24$ and use that to solve for $d$.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to calculate the second moment of $A_x$?

Comment: The second moment ${}^2 A_x$ at force of interest $\delta$ is equal to the first moment $A_x$ at force of interest $2\delta$.  That's why the problem gives you the value of $\ddot{a}_x$ at force of interest $2\delta$.